# Cannot override MUI React style with className CSS on Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I cannot over-ride the background colors of a MUI `<Button/>` component.
I'm trying to change the button background color on click.

```
    <Button 
      variant='text'
      className={` ${isWatched ? 'active ' : 'inactive '}`}      
      onClick={ handleWatchSelection }
    > .... </Button>
```

I can get it to work when using it like this:

```
    <Button 
      variant='text'
      sx={{
        bgcolor: `${isWatched ? 'red' : 'blue'}`
      }}      
      onClick={ handleWatchSelection }
    >
```

But, I don't render the styling on the button until the next batch of states render. So I get an effect where the styling change 'lags' behind each render cycle.

(example: click Button#1, and I see nothing. Click Button #2 and styling on Button#1 appears, but Button#2 does not change. Click Button#3 and Button#2, but Button#3 does not change etc..etc..)

I see the class being applied when the state changes.

[image]

Yet, even using `backgrounud: red !imporant;` within my `.active` styles (which is within my index.css & app.css folders) it is not registering.

Below is the MuiButton styling followed with my applied CSS classes (at the very bottom). If I remove `background-color: transparent` in dev tools, I

[image]

I feel like i'm missing something blatantly obvious, or is it the new MUI5 (which i've recently switched over to).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to [customize buttons in MUI5](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) .  If you are doing this globally, I would recommend overriding components in a [theme configuration](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/)

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I ended rendering the variant prop based off of the state change. For some reason, the initial solution posted above was not over-riding a specific MUI class.

I am using theme configuration, but will read deeper into the second links. Much appreciated!